# How to display extra info in custom info adapter with Arraylist(populated with data from KSOAP Webservice) using hashmap

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I made a custom info window that displays 5 info (Hospital name, Address, Fax, Mobile and Landline), I successfully displayed the Hospital and Address with the use of Title and Snippet when being pressed but not with the 3 last data. some blogs says I should use Hashmap to display extra data, but I am confused with their samples.

Code for marker:

```
ArrayList<MapConstants> _list = new ArrayList<MapConstants>(); _list.addAll(GlobalVariablesClass.FOR_MAPMARKER); 
for (int i = 0; i < _list.size(); i++) { 
    MarkerOptions markerOption = (new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(_list.get(i).getLatitude()), Double.valueOf(_list.get(i).getLongitude()))).title(bla).snippet(bla).icon(bla);
}
```

Comment: Provides some of your code to start with... You won't have so much helpful answers with such a vague description.

Comment: oh ok sorry.. I am new here in Stackoverflow so I cant post some clips of my work.but here's some of my code:

Code for marker:

 ArrayList<MapConstants> _list = new ArrayList<MapConstants>();
                _list.addAll(GlobalVariablesClass.FOR_MAPMARKER);

                for (int i = 0; i < _list.size(); i++)
                {
MarkerOptions markerOption = (new MarkerOptions()
                            .positiion (new LatLng(Double.valueOf(_list.get(i).getLatitude()),                                      Double.valueOf(_list.get(i).getLongitude())))
.title(bla)
.snippet(bla)
.icon(bla)
}

Comment: I made another class called mapConstants class so it will serve as external variable. and all the data has been stored in my external variable, now I dont know what to do next to display other info(Fax, Mobile, landline)

Comment: Please use the edit link too provide more information and enhance your question. I tried to move your code from comment to the question itself. Can you check there is no error in the code, and fix it if applicable. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem By doing this:

1st: I created a Class in which I'll get stored the return of webservice and use it for the marker. (mapConstants.Class)

MapConstants.Class:

public class MapConstants {

```
private String CLINIC_NAME, CLINIC_CODE,  UNIT_NO
    ,BLDG_NAME, STREET, COUNTRY, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, LANDLINE, MOBILE, FAX;


public MapConstants()
{

}

public MapConstants (String ClinicName, String ClinicCode, String UnitNo, String BuildingName
        , String Street, String Country, String Latitude, String Longitude, String Landline, String Mobile, String Fax)
{

    CLINIC_NAME = ClinicName;
    CLINIC_CODE = ClinicCode;
    UNIT_NO = UnitNo;
    BLDG_NAME = BuildingName;
    STREET = Street;
    COUNTRY = Country;
    LATITUDE = Latitude;
    LONGITUDE = Longitude;
    LANDLINE = Landline;
    MOBILE = Mobile;
    FAX = Fax;
}

public String setClinicName() {
    return this.CLINIC_NAME;
}

public String getClinicName() {
    return this.CLINIC_NAME;
}

public String setClinicCode() {
    return this.CLINIC_CODE;
}

public String getClinicCode() {
    return this.CLINIC_CODE;
}

public String setUnitNo() {
    return this.UNIT_NO;
}

public String getUnitNo() {
    return this.UNIT_NO;
}

public String setBldgName() {
    return this.BLDG_NAME;
}

public String getBldgName() {
    return this.BLDG_NAME;
}

public String setStreet() {
    return this.STREET;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return this.STREET;
}

public String setCountry() {
    return this.COUNTRY;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return this.COUNTRY;
}

public String setLatitude() {
    return this.LATITUDE;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return this.LATITUDE;
}

public String setLongitude() {
    return this.LONGITUDE;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return this.LONGITUDE;
}

public String setMobile(){
    return this.MOBILE;
}

public String getMobile(){
    return this.MOBILE;
}

public String setLandline(){
    return this.LANDLINE;
}

public String getLandline(){
    return this.LANDLINE;
}

public String setFax(){
    return this.FAX;
}

public String getFax(){
    return this.FAX;
}
```

}

2nd: On the method where you make your marker(In my case it is addmarkersToMapNew()), I made a Hashmap that will store other data you need aside from title and Snippet.

addMarkersToMapNew():

```
private void addMarkersToMapNew()
{
    //TODO addMarkersToMapNew
    int markerCount = 0;
    //ProgressDialog progDailog = null;

    if (ConnectionEcardMessage.isConnectingToInternet(SearchMapFragmentActivity.this))
    {
        ArrayList<MapConstants> _list = new ArrayList<MapConstants>();
        _list.addAll(GlobalVariablesClass.FOR_MAPMARKER);
        Log.i("addMarkersToMapNew-size", ""+_list.size());

        Log.i("addMarkersToMapNew", "ConnectionEcardMessage.isConnectingToInternet(SearchMapFragmentActivity.this)");
        if (mMapMarkers == null)
        {
            Log.i("addMarkersToMapNew", "null");
           mMapMarkers = new HashMap<String, MarkerOptions>();
           extraMarkerInfo = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            EcardMessage.appendLog("SearchMapFrag 6.5 - get curBranchDetails");


            for (int i = 0; i < _list.size(); i++)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> contactHashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Log.d("myApp", "added branch " + _list.get(i).getClinicName());

            MarkerOptions markerOption = (new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(  
                            new LatLng(Double.valueOf(_list.get(i).getLatitude()), 
                                       Double.valueOf(_list.get(i).getLongitude()))) 
                  .title(_list.get(i).getClinicName())                       .snippet(_list.get(i).getUnitNo()+""+_list.get(i).getBldgName()+","+_list.get(i).getStreet()+", "+_list.get(i).getCountry())
                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.address)));


                Log.i("Latitude_At_Longitude", "EDI WOW");

               contactHashmap.put("landline", _list.get(i).getLandline() );
               Log.i("kay landline", _list.get(i).getLandline());
               contactHashmap.put("mobile", _list.get(i).getMobile() );
               Log.i("kay Mobile", _list.get(i).getMobile());
               contactHashmap.put("fax", _list.get(i).getFax() );
               Log.i("kay Fax", _list.get(i).getFax());
               contactHashmap.put("title", _list.get(i).getClinicName());
               Log.i("kay title", _list.get(i).getClinicName());
               extraMarkerInfo.add(contactHashmap);

                mMapMarkers.put("Marker" + ++markerCount, markerOption);
                mMap.addMarker(markerOption);


            }

        }
}
```

3rd: After I saved the other Data that I need to display in Hashmap(extraMarkerInfo), I can now declare my Custom Info window:

Custom Info Window:

class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter
    {

```
    private final View myContentsView;


    MyInfoWindowAdapter(){
        myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        //TODO getInfoContents
        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());

        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

   //     private static HashMap<String, MarkerOptions> mMapMarkers = null;
        String landline = "";
        String mobile = "";
        String fax = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < extraMarkerInfo.size(); i++) {
            if (extraMarkerInfo.get(i).get("title").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(marker.getTitle()))
            {
                landline = extraMarkerInfo.get(i).get("landline").toString();
                Log.i("get_Landline", landline);
                mobile = extraMarkerInfo.get(i).get("mobile").toString();
                Log.i("get_Mobile", mobile);
                fax = extraMarkerInfo.get(i).get("fax").toString();
                Log.i("get_Fax", fax);
            }
        }

        TextView tvLandline = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.landline_number));
        tvLandline.setText(landline);

        TextView tvMobile = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_number));
        tvMobile.setText(mobile);

        TextView tvFax = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.fax_number));
        tvFax.setText(fax);

        return myContentsView;
    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

}
```